# Emission of all wavelengths by a single body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, temperature, thermal-radiation

A body at a constant temperature can emit radiations of all wavelengths. How is it? How it can emit all the wavelengths?

Comment: At **all** wavelengths, no. Look at the graph on this page and see how it declines at higher wavelengths. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body

Comment: Additionally, there will be no emission where there are no transitions.  For example, diamond does not radiate visible light, even when hot.  However, I have a feeling that the OP is after something else.  If so, please edit the questions.

Comment: one can't clear up your disbelief without knowing what assumptions led you to it.  Revise your question and someone is likely to help.

Answer (score 1):

If your body is an ideal blackbody it actually emits electromagnetic waves at all wavelengths according to Planck's blackbody radiation law. This can be explained by the electromagnetic field modes in the cavity of the black body, which have, in principle, no upper limit in frequency and thus energy of photons. The intensity of the radiation at higher frequencies, however, becomes smaller and smaller the higher the frequency becomes.A practical blackbody will probably not emit many gamma radiation photons.

Comment: That is different from what the OP is asking. Just because a body is at a constant temperature does not mean it can radiate all wavelengths. What if it was constantly at absolute zero or just above that? It still depends on how much energy is there.

Comment: According to Planck's  blackbody radiation law the whole spectrum of photon energies from 0 to infinity will be emitted if the blackbody is at any constant temperature above absolute zero. This occurs because according to the Bose-Einstein distribution of photons energies in electromagnetic modes there is no upper limit for the photon energies for a blackbody at a given finite absolute temperature. Very high energy photon emission probability only becomes extremely small. The ideal blackbody is in thermal equilibrium with an infinite thermal energy reservoir at finite absolute temperature.

Comment: two things: the op didn't mention blackbody, that's an assumption you're making.  Also, a detail, but the quantization changes the available modes of radiation for a thermal body.

Comment: @ ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird - As a physicist, you have usually to make simplifying assumptions. The blackbody radiation is such an assumption which is consistent with the question of the OP. You should know that it is exactly the quantization that leads to Planck's blackbody radiation law, which includes the energy occupation probability of all modes. If you know a better model than the blackbody radiation you are at liberty to give a better answer to  the OP question.

Comment: Thnkz a lot  thnkz thnkz...you gave me the ans. I want.@freecharly